# How to show all custom axes in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm writing a code to plot a graph with custom ticks (not ordered), this way:

```
axes1 = axes('Parent',figure,'XTickLabel',col1);
box(axes1,'on');
hold(axes1,'all');
plot(col2,'b*')
```

col1 and col2 are extracted from a matrix (each one have 1000 values). First values of col1 are: 120, 147, 644, 940 ...

The resulting image is the following: [image]

As you can see X axis follows the order I presented, but it should be 1000 values, not the 11 first values... How can I set X axis to col1 when col1 is not increasing (they are random numbers) and how can I make it fit with the points I want to show (col2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to adjust the [`XTick` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-XTick) of the axes, since it will only use as many of your labels as there are ticks, drawing them in order from the beginning of your `col1` array.

You have two general options: show *all* the labels (which will get messy since you have 1000) or show a sampling of labels. Here's an example of the first way:

```
% Sample data:
col1 = num2cell('a':'z');
col2 = 1:26;

axes1 = axes('Parent', figure, 'XTick', 1:numel(col1), 'XTickLabel', col1);
box(axes1, 'on');
hold(axes1, 'all');
plot(col2, 'b*');
```

[image]

And here's an example of the second way, showing only every fifth label:

```
axes1 = axes('Parent', figure, 'XTick', 1:5:numel(col1), 'XTickLabel', col1(1:5:end));
box(axes1, 'on');
hold(axes1, 'all');
plot(col2, 'b*');
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be what I was looking for, I'll try it, thanks!